# Get content div to hit bottom of the page

Tags: css, positioning

On http://audioaffair.co.uk why does the content div #pageSurround not hit the bottom of the browser window when there is sufficient content? (the black background shows through at the bottom even though all margins are 0px. So why does the body end early?)

On pages with less content like (https://www.audioaffair.co.uk/cart.php?act=cart)
how can I get the #pageSurround div to hit the bottom of the browser window.

Comment: You can play with min-height ( setting height of the element to be not lower than this value ) property of #pageSurround but i should warn you that not all browsers support it and you don't know what resolution user has thus avoid it. This site seems pretty fine if you ask me.

Comment: I have fixed the first problem using Czechnology answer. Still working with the second one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your first problem: that is because in CSS there is

```
.clearfix:after {
content: ".";
    /* ... */
}
```

So there's a dot between your `pageSurround` div (with `clearfix` class) and the bottom of the page.

As to your second problem: the link that [trevor posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531445/get-content-div-to-hit-bottom-of-the-page/5531480#5531480) should help you.

Comment: Yes yes!!! I can now fix the first problem. Now I see how the clearfix stuff works. Are the following needed in my CSS for clearfix to work?  
html[xmlns] .clearfix { display: block;}
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;}

Comment: I guess you've inherited the code from a previous designer? I'm not sure what your clearfix is supposed to do. Try experimenting with it, I guess it's probably not needed there...

Comment: No, I got the clearfix code from http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html when trying to solve another problem. A long time ago this site was not fixed width.

Comment: Aha. As I've said, try experimenting what setting fits your needs.

Comment: Just to make sure, this pseudo class :after won't work in ie.6.